# Image comparison slider does not work properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, web, slider, touch

I am constructing a web-site from scratch and I am using the following code from W3 to implement an image comparison slider : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp

I implemented it in my web-site succesfully, and it works just fine on desktop browsers.
But unfortunately, it does not work too well on some mobile devices.

If you try it on a samsung tab 3 or any other samsung device (even other brands as well), once you "touch" the slider, it does not move, unless you "touch" again in a different position, the slider will move to that position.
It is more of a click here and there rather than a slider.

I tried debugging with javascript (not an expert here) but I didnt manage to actually find something conclusive.
I saw that both "mouse" and "touch" events are managed...

You can test it directly by going to above link and go to developer tools / as galaxy tab 3

Comment: Same here, the solution from the above link does not work on mobile.